# EntityFramework & SQL Relationships inconsistency

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Main Question : How can i access my UserOrganization table from dbContext, or what i did wrong (cause i don't have it in my edmx, it isn't mapped by the orm) ?

I want to work with 3 tables.

One is User with primary key UserId.

One is Organization which has a composite primary key OrganizationId, DbConnection which represents the external db connection string.

And one is the middle-ware one UserOrganization where i have a composite primary key UserId, OrganizationId and DbConnection.

Entity Framework didn't map my UserOrganization table, instead it will just create a hashSet of organizations in user class, and a hashSet of users in organization class.

UserId is foreignKey in User and the composite DBConnection, OrganizationId is foreignKey in Organization.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to force Entity Framework which is an ORM to work in a "relational" way.
The purpose of ORMs is to hide those details and let you work directly with your domain objects.
In the end, adding a record in your UserOrganization table, means adding a User to an Organization.
If you're using an ORM, try not to "swim against the current" and think in objects instead of tables.

Comment: Yea, i suspected that was the "problem". So based to that i eliminate my composed primary key from userOrganization, I added a UserOrganizationId as PK with identity property, and i keep only my foreign keys and everything is alright now.